# Mounting S3 Bucket To NAS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, samba, s3fs

I'm wanting to mount an S3 Bucket to NAS and I would think it would be possible, has anyone ever done such a thing?

I would be using s3fs and a samba server.

Comment: There's a significant impedance mismatch between SMB and S3.  You can bridge it with Samba and s3fs, and it works but is somewhat sluggish due to synchronous operations that block until completion  I believe this is a question for a different site, although I'm not sure which: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), [Super User](https://superuser.com), or perhaps [Linux/Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  Please check those for a solution, and the post to the most appropriate one -- don't cross-post.

Comment: Possibly, the official [iSCSI-based S3 Volume (block) Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) would be a cleaner option for connecting your Samba server to S3.